# I am using LiveCode Community 6.5 and can not use a particular addin

Tags: livecode

Why can't I use an addin that was previously programmed to work with the application I am modifying.  This addin wordreport searches and replaces keywords used to represent variables in a word document.  Can addins be added to the Community version of LiveCode?  Are some allowed and others (encrypted) not allowed?

Comment: Probably you mean "plug-in" rather than addin. Please, include the version numbers of the LiveCode release your plug-in works with and the version number of the release it doesn't work with. Monte's suggestion that the plug-in is password-protected is probably right (but it is wrong to say that password protection violates the GPL).

Answer (score 4):

The plugin in question is quite likely password protected. The community edition does not support password protected stacks because if the code to password protect stacks were released in the GPL version it would make it redundant because anyone with a few minutes to spare could work out a way to unlock any password protected stack.

My suggestion is you contact the plugin author to see if it is or will be dual licensed at some point in the future.

Comment: Password protection in no way contradicts the GPL. A stack is a document and documents are separate pieces of work, not subject to the license of the tool they were made with. Only if you distribute your document as a standalone, i.e. together with other open-source components, the GPL applies.

Comment: I have amended my answer to remove the line about it being contrary to the GPL even though I meant only contrary to the spirit of it.

Comment: The removal of the security code from the community edition was to protect authors who do not wish to release their products as open source. If the security code were included in the OSS edition, no author could ever secure their work or their code. As one of those authors who needs to protect commercial-grade software for my cients, it is essential that the security algorithms are never exposed. In fact, the vendors group had a long discussion with the team about exactly that when RR were in the process of deciding whether or not to include the algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

The plugin in question is quite likely password protected. The community edition does not support password protected stacks because RunRev needs to provide an incentive for LiveCode users to buy a license.

Since you (seem to) have an older version of LiveCode, you can continue to use the plug-in with the older version. You might even make a standalone that includes the plug-in, so you don't need to have the entire LiveCode IDE in memory while using the plug-in.

As Monte suggests, you could contact the author of the plug-in and ask for a solution.

Comment: -1 for stating that password protection being removed from the community edition is about creating an incentive for LiveCode users to buy a license. They can not include that feature in an open source version without exposing all commercial products built with LiveCode.

Comment: And not exposing your commercial products is the main reason to buy a license.